# Help with finding distribution of Gaussian mixture

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I'm a bit stuck on this:

[image]

1. I'm trying to find the unconditional pdf of X, f(x).  I think it would be f(x,theta)/Gaussian but I'm not too sure about this and what f(x,theta) would be.
2. I'm also trying to find the conditional distribution of THETA|X but am unsure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution $p(x)$ (or $f(x)$ as you choose to call it) is usually referred to as the *marginal* distribution of $X$. It's computed by summing/integrating out, or *marginalizing out*, all other variables from the joint distribution,

1. $\displaystyle p(x)=\sum_ip(x,\theta_i)=\sum_ip(x|\theta_i)p(\theta_i)=\ldots\;$ can you take it from here?
2. By Bayes' rule, $\;\displaystyle p(\theta=\theta_i|x)=\frac{p(x|\theta_i)p(\theta_i)}{p(x)}$.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful